# m3u8 file in HTTP live streaming?

Tags: iphone, ipad, http-live-streaming

is m3u8 file a single file maintained in server for live streaming?is MPMoviePlayerController  enough for live streaming to show a TV channel? what are the other possibilities?any help please?I have verified [the Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what  you're asking for.

Anyways, I can talk you about our app. We host a variant playlist (m3u8) which links to three other playlist (high, medium and for 64kbps) and each one links to specific video segments of 10 secs. So yes, the playlist is hosted in the server.

And also yes, you can use MPMoviePlayerController or even load a UIWebView, which it will call the mediaplayer itself.

Remember that if you're planning to publish your app to the AppStore, you need to work under Apple restrictions regarding mobile network.